# Why does Autoresizing disappear when constraints are added?

Tags: xcode

When you create a new label in the storyboard, the Size Inspector menu looks like this: [image]

But as soon as you add constraints, the Autoresizing disappears: [image]

Why does this happen?
Is it impossible for an item to be resizeable while constrained?

Answer (score 1):

No , it's not possible these are 2 separate ways to layout an element you can't have both at the same time , either with the old springs and struts ( Discouraged  now ) or using auto-layout ( Recommended ) and that for pretty a lot of limitations regarding the old way look [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2856-beginning-auto-layout-in-ios-6-part-1-2) discussing some problems